# Solution to a two-inequality system

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider constants $a,b,c,d \in [0, 2\pi)$. I am trying to solve the system of inequations in unknowns $(x,y)$, where $x \in [0,\infty)$ and $y \in [0,2 \pi)$:

$$
\begin{cases}
      \Big( (\sin(y-a) - \sin(y-b))x + \sin(a-b) \Big) \Big( (\sin(y-c)-\sin(y-d))x + \sin(c-d) \Big)>0 \\ \Big( (\sin(y-a) - \sin(y-d))x + \sin(a-d) \Big) \Big( (\sin(y-b)-\sin(y-c))x + \sin(b-c) \Big)>0 \\
    \end{cases}
$$

Now, I see those as basically two inequalities in a quadratic function in $x$. For example, the quadratic function in the first inequality has roots
$$x_1 = \frac{\sin(b-a)}{\sin(y-a)-\sin(y-b)} = \frac{\cos \frac{b-a}{2}}{\cos ( y- \frac{a+b}{2})}, \qquad \text{and} \qquad x_2 = \frac{\cos \frac{d-c}{2}}{\cos ( y- \frac{c+d}{2})}$$
however here things get complicated because if $(\sin(y-a) - \sin(y-b))(\sin(y-c)-\sin(y-d))>0$ then $x \in (-\infty, \min(x_1,x_2)) \cup (\max(x_1,x_2),+\infty)$, and if coeff$<0$, then $x \in (\min(x_1,x_2),\max(x_1,x_2))$. The problem here is that because $y$ varies we can get the coefficient to be both negative and positive.

In theory if we do case work in terms of $y$ which would then give us the sign of each $\deg 2$ coefficient we could solve the inequality **if** we can also determine $\min(x_1,x_2)$ and $\max(x_1,x_2)$.

The problem is that I personally don't think that this approach is worthwhile in the sense that it's a brute force that may not even work.

I conjecture that the first inequality implies $x \geq 1$ and that the second implies $x \leq 1$ (this is because of the cyclicity of the inequalities), however the only way that I can see this being proven is by contradiction.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get this from?